# Simple question regarding limits

Tags: calculus, limits

If I know that:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) = 0 $$
and I want to perform: $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = (x+f(x))^3- x^3$

Can I do that: $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = (x+0)^3- x^3 = x^3 - x^3 = 0$ ?

Thanks :)

Comment: your last line of calculations has an equality that is wrong: you cannot pass to the limit when $\;x\to\infty\;$ in one part and leave $\;x\;$ as it is in other. When this is "done" there **must** be ajustification proving it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\;f(x)=\frac1x\;$ and get a straightforward counterexample

Comment: You were faster!$~~$

Comment: my calculus is a little rusty, I have an idea as to the answer, can you verify that I am right?

Comment: @Malachi Yes. Will you post a question?

Comment: It can even converge too a non-zero limit : _i.e_ with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ so this is quite much randomness.

Comment: That's correct, @Malachi. In fact, we can find examples where it'll converge to **any** real number we wish. In your example, it'll converge to $\;3\;$ .

Comment: I need to look at my Calculus book again....it's been a while @Timbuc. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, did not meant any identity theft I swear that was all against my will :D

Comment: @Timbuc, is understand it's not working, but aren't my steps legit?

Comment: I mean, I thought that given an existing limit, I can calculate limits like this, but it seems that it's not working, was I wrong?

Comment: @user1326293 Where you write "Can I do...?" , the answer is **no, you can't**, and the counterexample shows this. Read also my comment, perhaps even more important than the answer itself, below your question.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take for example $f(x)=\frac1x$ then

$$(x+f(x))^3-x^3=3x+\frac3x+\frac1{x^3}\xrightarrow{x\to\infty}+\infty$$

Comment: Hi, can you share how you developed this expression? thanks :)

Comment: I used the identity:
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+a^3$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b)^3-a^3=3 a^2 b+3 a b^2+b^3$$

Then take $f$:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) = 0 $$

And take an $g(x)$:

$$(g(x)+f(x))^3-g^3(x)=3g^2(x)f(x)+3f^2(x)g(x)+f^3(x)$$

From that you can see that:

- If you have a bounded limit for $g$ then your limit is $0$
- If $f(x)g^2(x)$ and $f^2(x)g(x)$ tends to $0$ then your limit is $0$

For that you could make a lot of counterexamples in which pass the  limit $f(x)$ is not valid.